# Convert Datetime in Epoch-Python

Tags: python, datetime, converters

I want to convert a `datetime` into epoch.

For example, I have `datetime` in this format: `2018-02-14T22:15:00.232029+01:00`.

How can I convert it into epoch? I get a lot of errors when i try to use `datetime` or `timestamp` in python,because of my datetime's format. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way:

```
import pandas as pd

base = '1970-01-01'
x = '2018-02-14T22:15:00.232029+01:00'

(pd.to_datetime(x) - pd.to_datetime(base)).total_seconds()

# 1518642900.232029
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!It works perfectly.Its exactly what i 've been searching for.

Answer (score 1):

Without using any external libraries:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%s.%f')
'1518655350.410295'
```